# Combine two arrays into one (append)

Tags: php, arrays

How can i combine two arrays in PHP like append them? I have tried **array_merge** but tis function returns me something else then I want. There is example:

Array 1 sample

```
[test1] => Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
)

[test2] => Array
(
    [0] => three
    [1] => four
)
```

Array 2 sample

```
[test1] => Array
(
    [0] => five
    [1] => six
)

[test2] => Array
(
    [0] => seven
    [1] => eight
)
```

Expected result

```
[test1] => Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => five
    [3] => six
)

[test2] => Array
(
    [0] => three
    [1] => four
    [2] => seven
    [3] => eight
)
```

Comment: have you looked at [array_merge_recursive()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want [`array_merge_recursive()`](http://php.net/array_merge_recursive):

```
$arr1 = array(
    'test1' => array('one', 'two'),
    'test2' => array('three', 'four'),
);

$arr2 = array(
    'test1' => array(2 => 'five', 3 => 'six'),
    'test2' => array(2 => 'seven', 3 => 'eight'),
);

$new_array = array_merge_recursive($arr1, $arr2);
print_r($new_array);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`array_merge_recursive`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) instead of `array_merge`.

```
$new_array_merged = array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2);
```